# PyQT QListWidget: limit selection to x items , disable rubber-band selection

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt4, pyside

I have a QListWidget instance with the following properties:

```
self.listWidget.setSelectionMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
self.listWidget.setSelectionBehavior(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.SelectItems)
self.listWidget.setViewMode(QtGui.QListView.IconMode)
```

I want to be able to select max 3 items only by clicking on them and not by rubber-band selection. The forth click should  deselect all previous selected items and select de current one. Rubber-band selection should be disabled.

I have done something like this with limited functionality of what I want to achieve: I must return a list of **max 3** `item.text()`of items selected . Rubber-band selection usage  may result in all items in the list being selected and returned as a list of `items.text()`.

```
myapp.listWidget.itemSelectionChanged.connect(icons_selected)

def icons_selected():
    L = [item.text() for item in myapp.listWidget.selectedItems()]

    if  L.__len__() <= 2 :
        myapp.listWidget. setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)

    if L.__len__() >= 3:
        myapp.listWidget. setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
        return L
```

Rubber-Band selection works regardless and I can end up with all the items selected. Which is something that I don't want.
I can workaround this by manipulating the `QAbstractItemView.NoSelection` but I think it's messy. 
I would rather be using something like  `setSelectionModel(QItemSelectionModel.NoUpdate)` , but don't know how to use it, can't figure it out.

Rubber-Band selection on all items :not what I want

[image]

LE:
this is what I've done:

```
self.listWidget.itemSelectionChanged.connect(self.get_selected_icons_list)
self.listWidget.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.restore_selection)


......

 def get_selected_icons_list(self):

       ....
        else:
            if icons_filename_list.__len__() <= 2:
                self.listWidget.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)

            if icons_filename_list.__len__() >= 3:
                self.listWidget.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.NoSelection)

            if not icons_filename_list:
                return None
            else:
                return icons_filename_list

    def restore_selection(self, *args):
        self.listWidget.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
        self.listWidget.clearSelection()
        self.listWidget.setCurrentItem(args[0])
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I accidentally  press submit before I finished . My post is now edited. this site is something I need to get used to.